# How to match multiple filename patterns and batch rename in a folder traversing bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to automate a task that, until now, I've manually performed with the rename utility. I don't have a lot of experience with bash, though, so I'm struggling to wrap my head around the complexity of it.

I have unsorted comics (.cbz files) which may take the following naming styles (actual examples - I may have missed some):

```
/Collection
├── /Title1
│   ├── _66.cbz
│   └── _Chapter 67.cbz
├── /Title2
│   ├── Chapter 117.cbz
│   └── Chapter 118 - Name.cbz
├── /Title3
│   ├── foo bar_Ch.10 - Name.cbz
│   ├── foo_Ch.21.cbz
│   └── foo_Ch.22.cbz
├── /Title4
│   ├── _Chapter 72_Voluminous.cbz
│   └── _Chapter 73_Final Chapter.cbz
├── /Title5
│   └── name.cbz
├── /Title6
│   └── Chapter 11 - Ch.11.cbz
└── /Title7
    ├── bar_Ch.58.2.cbz
    └── bar_Vol.11 Ch.58.1.cbz
```

As can be seen, the structure is a complete mess with no congruity between unsorted folders.
The general ruleset I've cooked up is the following:
(Feel free to change things up to make it work better)

1. If `.*Vol\.` is matched, remove everything before then i.e. replace with `Vol\.` (May also include 'Volume.2' but I don't recall seeing that)
2. Elif `.*Chapter` is matched, replace with `Ch\.`
3. Elif `.*Ch\.` replace with `Ch\.`
4. Elif nothing but the chapter number (`/Title1/_66.cbz`) precede it with `Ch.`
5. Else echo error
6. Replace `_` with `-` (space padded)

...for every *.cbz file in the directory

This should result in the following output:

```
/Collection
├── /Title1
│   ├── Ch.66.cbz
│   └── Ch.67.cbz
├── /Title2
│   ├── Ch.117.cbz
│   └── Ch.118 - Name.cbz
├── /Title3
│   ├── Ch.10 - Name.cbz
│   ├── Ch.21.cbz
│   └── Ch.22.cbz
├── /Title4
│   ├── Ch.72 - Voluminous.cbz
│   └── Ch.73 - Final Chapter.cbz
├── /Title5
│   └── name.cbz
├── /Title6
│   └── Ch.11.cbz
└── /Title7
    ├── Ch.58.2.cbz
    └── Vol.11 Ch.58.1.cbz
```

I've tried a few things so far, but nothing with this large scope. Note that some of the chapter names may include Vol or Cha.

The remaining parts of this I can probably solve myself. They include things like having the script apply to the contents of every /title in /collection so I only need to run it once from the parent directory.

Comment: https://github.com/comictagger/comictagger ?

Comment: @jhnc this doesn't appear to suit my purposes. comicvine also doesn't appear to have entries for many of my titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make a regex that directly matches everything that you need, but it's complicated and unmaintainable. In that sense you're right to decompose the problem in smaller parts. You shouldn't be using so many `sed` calls in the loop tho; actually, `bash` can capture the data directly, you don't even need `sed` at all.

The following solution has a few shortcomings, for ex. the "volume" must be located prior to the "chapter" in the filename, but it should work for your purpose:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for file in \
    Ch.33/_66.cbz '_Chapter 67.cbz' 'Chapter 117.cbz' 'Chapter 118 - Name.cbz' \
    'foo bar_Ch.10 - Name.cbz' foo_Ch.21.cbz foo_Ch.22.cbz '_Chapter 72_Voluminous.cbz' \
    '_Chapter 73_Final Chapter.cbz' bar_Ch.58.2.cbz 'bar_Vol.11 Ch.58.1.cbz'
do
    [[ $file =~ ^(.*/)?(.*)(\..*)$ ]]
    dirname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    filename=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    extension=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

    [[ $filename =~ Vol(ume)?[.\ ]([0-9]+) ]]
    volume=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

    filename=${filename#*"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}

    [[ $filename =~ Ch(apter)?[.\ ]([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*) ]]
    chapter=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}

    [[ ${chapter:+X} ]] || {
        printf 'illegal filename: %q\n' "$file" 1>&2
        continue
    }
    filename=${filename#*"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}

    [[ $filename =~ [_\ ]+(-\ +)?(.*)$ ]]
    title=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

    filename=${volume:+Vol."$volume" }Ch.$chapter${title:+ - "$title"}
    printf '%q %q %q\n' mv "$file" "$dirname$filename$extension"
done
```

```bash
mv Ch.33/_66.cbz Ch.33/Ch.66.cbz
mv _Chapter\ 67.cbz Ch.67.cbz
mv Chapter\ 117.cbz Ch.117.cbz
mv Chapter\ 118\ -\ Name.cbz Ch.118\ -\ Name.cbz
mv foo\ bar_Ch.10\ -\ Name.cbz Ch.10\ -\ Name.cbz
mv foo_Ch.21.cbz Ch.21\ -\ Name.cbz
mv foo_Ch.22.cbz Ch.22\ -\ Name.cbz
mv _Chapter\ 72_Voluminous.cbz Ch.72\ -\ Voluminous.cbz
mv _Chapter\ 73_Final\ Chapter.cbz Ch.73\ -\ Final\ Chapter.cbz
mv bar_Ch.58.2.cbz Ch.58.2\ -\ Final\ Chapter.cbz
mv bar_Vol.11\ Ch.58.1.cbz Vol.11\ Ch.58.1\ -\ Final\ Chapter.cbz
```

Comment: why should I not be using sed? From a maintainability standpoint?

Comment: I don't understand the first line after ```for file in```. Do I have to manually list every file I want to make modifications to?

Comment: that’s how you use a `for` loop; listing the items that you want to iterate through. Those items can be the result of a glob expansion like you did with `*.cbz` or listed manually like I did . You can put whatever fits your needs there

Comment: the main reason for avoiding `sed` is that you’ll have to use inside the `for` loop, which will slow down the script by a few orders of magnitude when processing a lot of files. The other reason is that you’re handling filenames here, which requires a different approach; for ex. the use of `sed -z`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Bash scripts are difficult to understand with my proficiency so I wasn't sure if what you had written required a hard-written list of files to operate on.
Regarding speed, it's likely a non-issue. I don't anticipate anything much greater than ~1000 files at a time which shouldn't take long.

Comment: on a test run this appears to have replaced 'Vol.1 Ch.5.cbz' with 'Vol.1 Ch.5 - Ch.120.cbz' and 'Chapter.7.cbz' with 'Ch.7 - Ch.120.cbz'.
Could you also elaborate on the 'edge cases' you mentioned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247058/discussion-between-grphine-and-fravadona).

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
find /Collection -name "*.cbz" | while read file; do
   dir=$(dirname $file)
   fileName=$(basename $file)
   case "$fileName" in 
     *Vol*)
       newFileName=$(echo $fileName | sed -E 's/[^0-9]+([0-9]{2,3})/Vol.\1/;s/_/ - /')            
       ;;
     *)
       newFileName=$(echo $fileName | sed -E 's/[^0-9]+([0-9]{2,3})/Ch.\1/;s/_/ - /')
     ;;
   esac
   mv $file $dir/$newFileName
done
```

Where `find` search every file with `cbz` extension in `Collection` folder, then apply a different regex for file with "Vol" string and for the other.

The regex:

- `[^0-9]+` search any char not in range 0-9
- `([0-9]{2,3})` followed by 2 or 3 number

You can use this [online sed](https://sed.js.org/) that can help.

Comment: I wish I knew about that online sed. I'd been experimenting the hard way haha

Comment: this appears to give me the following error ```sed: -e expression #1, char 30: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```. I haven't been able to determine which it happens to since there are so many, but it doesn't appear to be all of them.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot -E for Extended regular expression. I updated answer.